# Using shadows as an input in cycles?

Tags: materials, shadows

I'm trying to create a cartoon styled animation, and I'd like to give shadows a texture separately from the rest of the material, similar to [this video](https://youtu.be/-cw2gXq83n8?t=5m8s) at around 5:00, but not in real time. Is there a way to use the amount of light hitting the object as an input for the node editor, or will I have to use compositing?

Comment: Check here: http://blendernpr.org/downloads/ - Textured Toon